# Realm Java Migration: Property has been made required

Tags: java, android, realm, realm-java

Works fine for most fresh installs, but a lot of reports are coming in with this issue after the latest app update. It has been awhile between updates, so I THINK this could be caused by users updating from a very old version before I added schema...but others have said they have seen this from a fresh install. Realm Java is `realm-gradle-plugin:5.1.1`

I appreciate any help, thanks!

**The Error:**

```
Caused by io.realm.exceptions.RealmMigrationNeededException
Migration is required due to the following errors: - Property 'Loan.loanRatePct' has been made required.
...
...onCreate (Activity.java:168)
```

**MyMigration.java**

```
if (oldVersion == 0) {
    schema.get("Storage")
            .addField("heat", String.class);
    oldVersion++;
}

if (oldVersion == 1) {
    schema.get("Env")
            .addField("gameType", String.class);
    oldVersion++;
}

if (oldVersion == 2) {
    schema.get("Loan")
            .addField("loanRatePct", Double.class);
    schema.create("GameMode")
             .addField("md", String.class)
            .addField("name", String.class)
            .addField("days", int.class)
            .addField("term", int.class)
            .addField("rate", String.class)
            .addField("amount", int.class)
            .addField("icon", int.class);
    schema.create("Leaderboard")
            .addField("score", String.class);

    oldVersion++;
}

if (oldVersion == 3) {
    schema.get("Leaderboard")
            .addField("mode", String.class);
    oldVersion++;
}
```

**MyApplication.java**

```
Realm.init(getApplicationContext());
    RealmConfiguration config = new RealmConfiguration.Builder()
            //todo: EVERY UPDATE: is new schema needed?
            .schemaVersion(4) // Must be bumped when the schema changes
            .migration(new MyMigration()) // Migration to run instead of throwing an exception
            .build();
    Realm.setDefaultConfiguration(config);
```

**Activity.java**

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {    
    realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();
    ...
}
```

*Edit: forgot:*

**Loan.java**

```
public class Loan extends RealmObject {
    String theloan;
    int loan;
    int loanRate;
    double loanRatePct;
    int loanBalance;
}
```

Comment: `.addField("loanRatePct", Double.class);` should be `.addField("loanRatePct", double.class);`

Answer (score 28, accepted):

`Double` means `nullable double`.

`double` means `non-null double`.

So `.addField("loanRatePct", Double.class);` should be `.addField("loanRatePct", double.class);`.

Comment: note that you might need to bump the schema version and check if the field is nullable, and if so, then `setRequired("loanRatePct", true)`

Comment: You need to use `::class.javaPrimitiveType` for the non-null version in Kotlin.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. It's working. For those looking for an answer, you should use the primitive data-type instead of the Object in the second Parameter.